# How to place the buttons in UIStackView next to other based on condition?

Tags: ios, swift, button, stack

I have a stackview  in which I am adding the buttons dynamically. But I need to add the buttons based on the condition like below:

```
if trim.contains("0"){
        print("contaim 0")
        let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))
        button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button1.setTitle("No", forState: .Normal)
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button1)
    }
    if trim.contains("1") {
        print("contaim 1")

        let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 90, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))
            button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button2.setTitle("Less", forState: .Normal)
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
            button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            myStackview.addSubview(button2)


    }
    if trim.contains("2"){
        print("contaim 2")

        let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))
        button3.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button3.setTitle("Half", forState: .Normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button3)
    }
    if trim.contains("3"){
        print("contaim 3")
        let button4 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 210, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))

        button4.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button4.setTitle("On", forState: .Normal)
        button4.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button4)
    }
    if trim.contains("4"){
        print("contaim 4")
        let button5 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))

        button5.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button5.setTitle("With", forState: .Normal)
        button5.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button5)
    }
    if trim.contains("5"){
        print("contaim 5")
        let button6 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 310, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))

        button6.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button6.setTitle("On Burger", forState: .Normal)
        button6.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button6.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button6)
    }
    if trim.contains("6"){
        print("contaim 6")
        let button7 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 370, y: 0, width: 60, height: 20))

        button7.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button7.setTitle("On Chips", forState: .Normal)
        button7.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
        button7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        myStackview.addSubview(button7)
    }
```

here my buttons are adding but at given position in  stackview. My requirement is that, for example if button1  condition is not satisfied then 2nd button should come at the place of first  like that??

the buttons should behave like radiobuttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var posX = 0
var posY = 0
if trim.contains("0"){
print("contaim 0")
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))
button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
button1.setTitle("No", forState: .Normal)
button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button1)
posX = 60
}
if trim.contains("1") {
print("contaim 1")

let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))
button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
button2.setTitle("Less", forState: .Normal)
button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button2)
posX =  posX + 60
}
if trim.contains("2"){
print("contaim 2")

let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))
button3.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button3.setTitle("Half", forState: .Normal)
button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button3)
posX =  posX + 60
}
if trim.contains("3"){
print("contaim 3")
let button4 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))

button4.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button4.setTitle("On", forState: .Normal)
button4.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button4)
posX =  posX + 60
}
if trim.contains("4"){
print("contaim 4")
let button5 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))

button5.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button5.setTitle("With", forState: .Normal)
button5.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button5)
posX =  posX + 60
}
if trim.contains("5"){
print("contaim 5")
let button6 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))

button6.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button6.setTitle("On Burger", forState: .Normal)
button6.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button6.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button6)
posX =  posX + 60
}
if trim.contains("6"){
print("contaim 6")
let button7 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 60, height: 20))

button7.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

button7.setTitle("On Chips", forState: .Normal)
button7.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox untick.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button7.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myStackview.addSubview(button7)
}
```

Comment: its not working properly in all conditions. say for example if my two or more  button1, button2 is only satisfied then the button1 will come in  1st place but wat about button2 . it still will get the position 270 and the button is displaying with the space.

Comment: check the code again. I didn't run it. It should run properly now

Comment: one more thing  how can these buttons  behave like  radio button., because i know only thru storyboard. not dynamically